# Displaying DB table data on my website using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've seen this question asked in many ways but none that address my concerns nor are any of them at a very basic level like this one.

How do I display the data in my SQL database on my website? More specifically, how do I 
pick-and-choose which columns/fields I want to display?

EDIT: I have 3 fields/columns. ID, URL, IMAGE (each one with a unique value.)

Let's say I have 10 records/rows in my table. I want to display all 10 on my webpage BUT I need control over where each url and each image is placed on the page. Like all of the below just dump the chosen contents to the page.

I think I'm looking to assign variable values to each row of data. So I can then take that variable and place it on the page where I need it. IE:

```
'<a href=".$TABLE_URL_VARIABLE."><a>'
```

Not even sure if that's how it would look above but it's just an example

My code below

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('update_ad');

$sql = "select * from ads";
$query = mysql_query( $sql );

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
{
echo "$row[id]";
echo "$row[image]";
echo "$row[url]";
}

?>
```

Comment: i am still unable to realise what you exactly want ?

Comment: you can take one drop down box in it fetch all the ids from the table and onchange of the drop down box submit the form and in above query use id from dropdown box value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want to:

> IE: I have 50 records I only want to display the image and url for ID 1 some where on the page then display the image and url from ID 2 somewhere else.

You could loop through the table and put all values in an array. Something like:

```
$array_result = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
{
  $array_result[$row['id']] = array('image' => $row['image'], 'url' => $row['url']);
}
```

Then; somewhere else in your code, if you need the image for id 1, and the url for id 2. You can do something like:

```
echo $array_result[1]['image'] . $array_result[2]['url'];
```

Comment: This is the closest ive seen to what im looking for. still not complete tho

Comment: In the questions he says it's concerning about 50 records. For that this is not a bad solution.

Comment: I've tried this but I cant seem to add it into my pre existing code. I'm still a bit new sorry. Im sure its simple

Comment: I got it! thanks your answer was dead on. Now im using <?php echo $array_result[1]['image'] ?> to display things where I want them

Comment: Hey real fast, If i wanted to add in three more fields in the table so id, url, image, title, text, misc, ? How to also put them in the array?

Comment: I got that to lol   $array_result[$row['id']] = array('image' => $row['image'], 'urls' => $row['urls'], 'title' => $row['title'], 'misc' => $row['misc']);

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is that if you use Select *, you will be returned with everything from your table. Your need to rewrite the query and its always nice and easier to use a parameterized query.

The query of something like this

```
SELECT `id`,`image`,`url` FROM ads WHERE id IN (3, 23, 41)
```

Even if you did

```
SELECT * FROM ads WHERE id IN (3, 23, 41)
```

You will get the same results from both queries since you have only 3 columns in your table but its just for good practice I guess to write parameterised queries.

Secondly, please look up using **mysqli** instead of **mysql** as mysql seems to be depreciated. I use mysqli and you really won't find a huge difference in the syntax. There is even an option of using PDO but I have not used it myself so I can;t comment much but you could have a look at it.

If you like video's watch this http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=113 and the next part as well for using mysqli and if you like to read, have a look at this article http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should

In any case back to your question, once you set up your connections and used the new query, then you follow your same technique of looping with mysqli_fetch_assoc and you either echo it, store it in another variable to be used anywhere else on your site.

Hope this helped.

Thanks, Shawn

Answer (score 0):

Try to use limit and order by. Limit 3 will fetch only 3 records and order by RAND() will randomly fetch the records from the database. Instead of * give the field names.

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('update_ad');

$sql = "select id,image,url from ads order by RAND() limit 3";
$query = mysql_query( $sql );

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
{
echo "$row[id]";
echo "$row[image]";
echo "$row[url]";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple programming... Either you can select this during the loop

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)   )
{
   if(!in_array($row['id'],array(3,41,25))
       continue;
   echo "{$row['id']}";
   echo "{$row['image']}";
   echo "{$row['url']}";
}

?>
```

Or you can do this during sql select

```
$sql = "select * from ads where id in (3,41,25)";
```

also mysql_functions are deprecated use mysqli or PDO

Comment: First example isn't good idea. Such operations should be done on database level. But + for mentioning about mysql_* functions.

Comment: Better not to provide an answer with mysql_* functions then in the first place ;-)

Comment: u mean change the original context and rewrite the code in PDO ? bit of an overkill plus doesn't solve the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe you're looking for `IN`?

```
SELECT * FROM ads WHERE id IN (3, 23, 41)
```

It'll select only three records with that IDS.

Edit: If you want to use all records just assign each row to array. Before loop declare `$results = array();` and in loop use `$results[$row['id']] = $row;`.
In every place that you want to use fetched row just write something like `echo $results[15]['url'];` to get url from row with ID = 15.

And first of all, start using PDO.